# A fast way to check if a Matrix is ill-conditioned, and turning it into well-conditioned

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver

I'm running a simulation, and some linear solvers are returning a message of ill-conditioned matrix.

Hence, I'm looking for a fast, easy to implement, method to detect if a matrix is ill-conditioned, before using the linear solver. And in case it's ill-conditioned, what's good way to make it well-conditioned?

Comment: You need to understand at a higher level why your system of equations is ill-conditioned.  The proper solution will almost certainly lie within the process that is generating these systems of equations.

Comment: The method of letting LU-decomposition (with or without pivoting) run its course is a valid way of checking whether the matrix is ill-conditioned. The other measures common to NLA are actually more expensive. On the practical side I agree with @BrianBorchers

Comment: I will third this: If the matrix you have in your linear system is ill-conditioned, then it is ill-conditioned. If you want to change the matrix, you change the linear system, so you get a solution to a different problem. You need to find out *why* it is ill-conditioned, not patch over it.

Comment: @BrianBorchers please, can you expand your comment? I would be particularly interested in  inverse problems. In these cases can you improve the generating process? Or you must work with regularization?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think this is a little bit pessimist view, i.e. with preconditioning same cases, not all, can be manage without change the math problem. Am I too optimistic?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: You recommend the hard route; often that recommendation ends in a research problem. The easy route is simply using a floating point type such that $\mathrm{cond}(A) \ll 1/\mu$. Not always an option in a realtime or HPC environment, but almost always an option for everyone else.

Comment: @MauroVanzetto: Preconditioning is for poorly conditioned matrices, i.e., with bad but not terrible condition numbers. But when a linear solver says that the matrix is ill-conditioned, then that's often an indication that one is either using a poorly chosen formulation, or that there is a bug in the code. In either case, it's important to *understand* the cause of the conditioning, not to paper over it.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth ok, I  understand what you mean. Indeed, the best thing would be to eradicate the problem at its roots, but this is not always possible. Try to think to inverse problems, here there is little room for maneuver. And for this reason exist a branch of math for the study of regularization of problems. In this line my reasoning goes, in past I solve problem of ill-conditioned with preconditioning (some works to find the good preconditioner and maybe not so ill), and other with regularization technique.

Answer (score 2):

To detect if a matrix is ill-conditioned you can check the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) defined, for the matrix $A$
as:
$$
k(A) = ||A|| \, ||A^{-1}||
$$

For norm 2 this is equal to the ratio of singular values:
$$
k(A) = \frac{\sigma_{max}(A)}{\sigma_{min}(A)} 
$$

Numerically there are also other methods to estimate $k(A)$. For more details see chapter 15 of [1], and [2] where you can find source code for different methods (Hager, from LINPACK, sampling) in  different languages.

To threat an ill-conditioned system there are two principal ways:

**preconditioning:** using this technique you obtain a system mathematically equivalent to the start situation, but with a better condition number. The methods depend on the structure of the matrix that you have, but you can see for example [3] for iterative methods.

**regularization:** here you obtain an approximation of the starter system, these methods work also for ill-posed problem. Example of techniques in this family are:

- [truncated svd](http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/na/m/86/36/NA-M-86-36.pdf) essentially you discard the smallest singular values
- [Tikhonov Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)

For more details and references see for example [4].

---

[1] *Higham, Nicholas J.*, [**Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898718027), Philadelphia, PA: SIAM. xxx, 680 p. (2002). [ZBL1011.65010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1011.65010).

[2] web page [Matrix Condition Number Estimation](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/condition/condition.html)

[3] *Saad, Yousef*, Iterative methods for sparse linear systems., Philadelphia, PA: SIAM Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics. xviii, 528 p. (2003). [ZBL1031.65046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1031.65046).

[4] [REGULARIZATION TECHNIQUESBASED ON KRYLOV SUBSPACE METHODSFOR ILL-POSED LINEAR SYSTEMS](https://www.math.unipd.it/~gazzola/gazzola_silvia_tesi.pdf)